# Manipulating Documentclass thesis in latex

Tags: spacing

I am writing my thesis in the following documentclass

```
 \documentclass[11p,
topenright,
twoside,
openright,
plainfootsepline,                               
headsepline,                                                    
tocindent,                                                          
listsindent,                                                        
tablecaptionabove,                                          
halfparskip,                                                    
%bibtotoc,                                                      
a4paper]{thesis}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        % euro quality fonts [T1] (togeth. w/textcomp)
\usepackage{textcomp, amssymb}  % additional symbols (there are more packages)
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}   % umlaute in input file
%\usepackage{setspace}           % doublespacing
\usepackage{anysize}            % margin package sets tighter margins
\usepackage[all]{xy}            % creating figures within latex
\usepackage[tight]{subfigure}% subfigures: figures within figures
\marginsize{1.2in}{0.9in}{0.5in}{1.5in} % small margins
\usepackage{flafter}
\usepackage{ifpdf}              % if pdflatex then ... else ...
\ifpdf
\pdfadjustspacing=1           % make pdflatex behave like latex
\usepackage{aeguill}          % PS converted CM fonts for better acro preview
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx} % graphics packages
\usepackage[pdftex]{color}    % color packages
\usepackage[pdftex]{thumbpdf} % create thumbnails (run thumbpdf as well)
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[pdftex,%
pdfsubject={PhD Thesis},%
]{hyperref}        % clickabe references
\else
\usepackage[hypertex,
plainpages=false, % distinguish roman and arabic pagenumbers
linktocpage=true, % toc etc: make page number active (not name)
]{hyperref}        % clickabe references in .dvi
% purposely included before color package
\usepackage[dvips]{color}     % color packages; needed by xy
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}  % graphics packages
\fi
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,amsfonts,amsbsy,latexsym}
\usepackage{float}  
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{dunkelgrau}{rgb}{0.7,0.7,0.7}
\definecolor{hellgrau}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}
\definecolor{hellgrau_1}{gray}{0.95}
\usepackage{makeidx}                       % for \printindex
\makeindex                                 % creates paper.idx index 
\usepackage[style=super, cols=3]{glossary} % for \printclossary
\makeglossary                              % creates paper.glo 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks   = true,
    citecolor    = red
}
%*****************************
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{setspace}
%********************************************
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}  
\usepackage{type1ec}                                    
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{}                    
\renewcommand\bibname{References}
\makeatletter
\let\orig@bibliography\bibliography
\let\orig@thebibliography\thebibliography
\let\orig@include\include
\let\orig@cite\cite
\let\orig@nocite\nocite
\let\orig@bibliographystyle\bibliographystyle
\makeatother
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{1em}{3.2em}}
\renewcommand*\l@table{\@dottedtocline{1}{1em}{3.2em}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{type1ec}    
\usepackage{amsthm}                             
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{}    
\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadings
\clearscrplain
\usepackage[headsep = 15mm,                         
footskip            = 2\baselineskip,           
footnotesep         = 07mm,                             
top                 = 25mm,                         
bottom              = 20mm,                             
left                = 29mm,                              
right               = 29mm,                         
bindingoffset       = 07mm,                         
includefoot]{geometry}
\ofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
%****************************************
\ohead[]{\headmark}
\setfootsepline{.2pt}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{equation}}
```

I have a lot of extra spaces in the first page of each chapter, as it is attached.
[image]
How I can decrease the spaces?

Thesis.cls is as follow:

```
% my thesis

% First identify the class:

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{thesis}

\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{report}}

\ProcessOptions

\LoadClass{report}

% add dots to chapters in TOC
\renewcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode \bfseries
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      #1\nobreak \leaders\hbox{$\m@th\mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep mu$}  \hfil \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
      \penalty\@highpenalty
    \endgroup
  \fi}


% no indentation for paragraphs and space inbetween paragraphs  (euro standard)
% this happens to spread also the table of contents, list of figures and tables
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{7pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}


% Make the captions in your floats of the form:
% Figure 1 -> Fig. 1

\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}


% force footnotes to the bottom
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}


% Redefining the \section command:

%\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection
%{section}%                   % the name
%{1}%                         % the level
%{0mm}%                       % the indent
%{-\baselineskip}%            % the before skip
%{0.5\baselineskip}%          % the after skip
%{\normalfont\large\itshape}} % the style


% Redefining the chapter heading styles

% Numbered chapter heading style:

\renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{%
  {\singlespacing
    \parindent \z@ \raggedleft \normalfont

    \vspace*{30mm}%  
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
    \fontsize{60}{70}\selectfont \scshape \bf \textsc \@chapapp\space \thechapter         % Chapter followed by number
    \par\nobreak
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \vspace{30mm}%  
    \huge \scshape \bf #1\par                                                            % chapter title
    \rule{\textwidth}{1pt}                                                               %horizontontal line                        
    \nobreak
   \vskip 40\p@
  }}

% Unnumbered chapter heading style:

\renewcommand{\@makeschapterhead}[1]{%
  {\singlespacing
    \parindent \z@ \raggedleft
    \normalfont
                                     % horizontal line
    \vspace{4pt}%                                            % add some vertical space
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \huge \scshape \bf #1\par                           % chapter title
    \vspace{4pt}% 
    \rule{\textwidth}{1pt}                                          % add some vertical space
    \nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}


% end of file:
\endinput
```

Comment: there are approximately 10000000 local classes called `thesis.cls` used in departments all round the world for local thesis requirements.  there is no way at all of knowing what code is inside the class you are using.

Comment: Thanks @David . I added more details; I hope with this details someone can help me

Comment: The main question can still not be answered as those settings are in your local thesis class that you have not shown, but your preamble  is vastly more complicated than you need, You can for example delete the lines  `\usepackage[pdftex]{color} `, `\usepackage[dvips]{color} ` and `\usepackage{color} ` which do nothing useful here, and similarly for several other packages that are referenced multiple times.

Comment: Dear David:I have added .cls file, hope to get help

Comment: Your preamble is hinting of using a KOMA-class internally, but your `thesis.cls` doesn't  match. Is this another case of *template confusion*? Replace the first line in your example with `\\usepackage[11pt]{report}` or `\usepackage{scrreprt}`.

Answer (score 2):

You are introducing the spaces yourself.

```
\renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{%
  {\singlespacing
    \parindent \z@ \raggedleft \normalfont

    \vspace*{30mm}%  <= Space here
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
    \fontsize{60}{70}\selectfont \scshape \bf \textsc \@chapapp\space \thechapter         % Chapter followed by number
    \par\nobreak
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \vspace{30mm}%    <= Space here
    \huge \scshape \bf #1\par                                                            % chapter title
    \rule{\textwidth}{1pt}                                                               %horizontontal line                        
    \nobreak
   \vskip 40\p@  <= Space here
  }}
```

You need to adjust the values to fit your needs.

Comment: Another `\@makechapterhead` answer by **you** ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer :-)